# Translating Currency Symbol in Transactional Emails

Tags: email-templates, email-translation

Is it possible to translate the currency symbol within transactional emails? For example I want to change USD to US.

Comment: all magento translate  email??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While nothing is impossible this will be a LOT of work, especially since you only want it in the emails. Prices generally come from included phtml files in the emails, you can find them by their handle in the `sales.xml` and probably `tax.phtml`layout files.

You might be able to wrap the `formatPrice` function that outputs the price with a translate string that converts USD into US. But again, it might just not be worth while to even get started on this